# Facebook 'caption' option not showing up for non-timeline Facebook

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

So I'm creating posts to the facebook user's wall using Graph API

I'm referring to the 'caption' as stated here:

http://nocturnsoft.com/devblog/?p=906

when I specified the 'caption' option, the text in the caption would appear properly for profiles that uses the timeline, but for profile that use the old style, the caption would not appear...

Am I doing something wrong here or is this how it's supposed to be....If it is how it's supposed to be, how would I display text beneath the link for the Facebook post for non timeline profiles

btw: I'm using Facebook PHP SDK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my apps the post data array looks like this and the caption (message) is present on both new and old profiles.

```
    /* post to fb */
$post = array(
    'access_token' => $fb_access_token,
    'message' =>  'THIS IS YOUR CAPTION HERE',
    'link' => 'LINK TO YOUR SITE OR APP HERE',
    'picture' => 'URL TO IMAGE HERE',
    'name' => 'APP NAME HERE',
    'description' => 'AWESOME DESCRIPTION ABOUT YOUR APP GOES RIGHT HERE!'
);
$res = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST', $post);
```

Hope this helps.  If so don't forget to say so! :)